# How to retrieve album list including total play time on iOS/MediaPlayer

Tags: ios, mpmediaquery

If you use `[MPMediaQuery genresQuery]` then you get `MPMediaItemCollection` which doesn't hold the total play time. You can use the `representativeItem` but this one gives you only that particular item play time.

Is there an efficient way how to display all albums including the total play time?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get playback time for the whole library then you just need to iterate through items in `MPMediaQuery`.

```
    let query = MPMediaQuery.albums()
    let items = query.items
    var totalTime: TimeInterval = 0.0
    if items != nil {
        for item in items! {
            totalTime += item.playbackDuration
        }
    }
    let duration = Int(totalTime)
    let seconds = duration % 60
    let minutes = duration / 60 % 60
    let hours = duration / 3600
    print("Total playback time: \(hours):\(minutes):\(seconds)")
```

Collections will give you an arrays of `MPMediaItems` sorted alphabetically and grouped in collections by `groupingType` options (artists, albums, genres, etc.). If you need for example playback time for every album in library then you can iterate like this:

```
    let query = MPMediaQuery.albums()
    let collections = query.collections
    var albumTime: TimeInterval = 0.0
    if collections != nil {
        for collection in collections! {
            if let albumTitle = collection.representativeItem?.value(forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle) {
                for item in collection.items {
                    albumTime += item.playbackDuration
                }
                let duration = Int(albumTime)
                let seconds = duration % 60
                let minutes = duration / 60 % 60
                let hours = duration / 3600
                print("\"\(albumTitle)\" playback time: \(hours):\(minutes):\(seconds)")
                albumTime = 0.0
            }
        }
    }
```